# exclude a page from a different page php

Tags: php

I have a question about on how to exclude a php page from another in an IF statement php.
this is my code:

```
   include 'category.php';
     if(isset($_SESSION['ageSearch'])){
      include 'age.php';
      //exclude category.php here; }
```

Any suggestion how to to that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply include `category.php` in `else` structure

```
if(isset($_SESSION['ageSearch'])){
    include 'age.php';
}
else{
   include 'category.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like that ?

```
if(isset($_SESSION['ageSearch'])){
    include 'age.php';
}
else
{
    include 'category.php';
}
```